# Check if the variable passed as an argument is set

Tags: php, isset

I want to check if a variable called $smth is blank (I mean empty space), and I also want to check if it is set using the function I defined below:

```
function is_blank($var){
    $var = trim($var);
    if( $var == '' ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't find a way to check if variable `$smth` is set inside `is_blank()` function. The following code solves my problem but uses two functions:

```
if( !isset($smth) || is_blank($smth) ){
    // code;
}
```

If I use an undeclared variable as an argument for a function it says:

```
if( is_blank($smth) ){
    //code;
}

Undefined variable: smth in D:\Www\www\project\code.php on line 41
```

Do you have a solution for this?

#### Solution

This is what I came up with:

```
function is_blank(&$var){ 
    if( !isset($var) ){ 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        if( is_string($var) && trim($var) == '' ){ 
            return true; 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

and works like a charm.  Thank you very much for the [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547060/15168), [NikiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385378/nikic).

Comment: *(sidenote)* `isset` is not a function but a language construct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply pass by reference and then do isset check:

```
function is_blank(&$var){
    return !isset($var) || trim($var) == '';
}
```

Comment: How about "return !isset($var) || !trim($var);" ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a variable outside of `empty` and `isset` it will be checked if it was set before. So your solution with isset is correct and you cant' defer the check into the `is_blank` function. If you only want to check if the variable is empty, use just the `empty` function instead. But if you want to specifically check for an empty string after a `trim` operation, use `isset` + your `is_blank` function.

Answer (score -1):

Use `empty`. It checks whether the variable is either 0, empty, or not set at all.

```
if(empty($smth))
{
    //code;
}
```

Comment: i know, that's why i didn't used it